# Connect to new object returns -3 in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc, powerbuilder-conversion

I am working on project where i am connecting dot net dll in powerbuilder . In dll project at dot net i am referencing two more dlls  . My project dll is made COM type and it has been registered successfully using regasm.exe "mydll.dll" in dot net version directory. I can see the registry entry in my windows registry but  when I test on other machine, it throws exception of connecting to com object failed return -3.

I am stuck badly and unable to figure out the solution.

Here in my code for powerbuilder:

```
dw_data.accepttext()
oleobject obj
obj= create oleobject
ll_obj= obj.connecttonewobject("classname")
IF ll_obj < 0 THEN
    DESTROY obj
    MessageBox("Verify","Connecting to COM Object Failed Error: " + String(ll_obj))
    Return
END IF
```

ll_obj returns -3 in other machines .

Any helping hand around ?

Comment: Have you registered the dll on the other machine too?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick Google search on 'connecttonewobject' I found this suggestion:

> Have all classes a strong name?
>
> Are all classes installed in the GAC?

Bruce Armstrong also suggests using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to assist in determining that all objects are deployed on the machine running the code.